# Set constraints to an image that is dynamically reduced in size. Swift

Tags: swift3

I have an logo that is quite large (58312 x 1478 px), I am reducing the size of it using alamofire image, and then setting constraints to  centre horizontally and vertically in the view (self.view) as shown below using Visual Flow Layout (VFL). 
With the below constraints the logo is not centred, can someone please advice where I am going wrong.

```
let viewWidth   =   self.view.bounds.width
let viewHeight  =   self.view.bounds.height


let logoView               =    UIImageView()
logoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let logo                        =   UIImage(named: "logo")
let logoSize                    =   CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 100.0)
let aspectScaledToFitImage      =   logo.af_imageAspectScaled(toFit: logoSize)

logoView.image                  =   aspectScaledToFitImage
self.view.addSubview(logoView)

let logoHeight         =    logoView.frame.size.height
let logoWidth          =    logoView.frame.size.width

let logoViewTopSpacing     =   (viewHeight / 2) + (logoHeight / 2)
let logoViewSideSpacing    =   (viewWidth / 2) + (logoWidth / 2)


let views = [
    "logoView"     :   logoView
]

// SETTING CONSTRAINTS
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-\(logoViewSideSpacing)-[logoView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-\(logoViewTopSpacing)-[logoView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that

by replacing the below

```
let imageWidth         =    aspectScaledToFitImage.size.width
let imageHeight         =    aspectScaledToFitImage.size.height


let logoViewTopSpacing     =   (viewHeight / 2) - (imageHeight / 2)
let logoViewSideSpacing    =   (viewWidth / 2) - (imageWidth / 2)
```

with

```
let logoHeight         =    logoView.frame.size.height
let logoWidth          =    logoView.frame.size.width

let logoViewTopSpacing     =   (viewHeight / 2) + (logoHeight / 2)
let logoViewSideSpacing    =   (viewWidth / 2) + (logoWidth / 2)
```

Solved the problem of centering the logo inside the view